# Ayuda c++ hilos Pausar y Reanudar

Tags: c++, hilos

Soy nuevo en esto de c++, este código lo hice practicamente con ayuda de paginas de internet.
 Quisiera saber como puedo pausar y reanudar dos hilos, que cuando yo inicio un hiloA llegue a un punto donde se detenga, luego el otro hiloB se inicie y llegue a un punto donde se detenga, luego vuelva con el hilo A, y así sucesivamente y al final mostrar los resultado.

Aquí el código :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include<iostream> //std::cout
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread> //std::thread
#include <mutex>

int prime(long int);
void ce();
long int cd(long int);
void encrypt();
void decrypt();
void calculoPi();
void RSA();
void hacerArchivo();
void printPossibleValues();
string leerArchivo();

using namespace std;

long int p, q, n, t, flag, e[100], d[100], temp[100], j, m[100], en[100], i;
char msg[100];
char resp;
std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
FILE *doc;
int numeroint = 0;
int salto = 0;
int porcentajetotal = 0;
int porcentajeB = 0;
int contadorDos = 0;
int iteradorDos = 0;
int cantIteracionesDos = 0;
int saltoDos = 0;
int porcentajeA = 0;
int porcentajeTempDos = 0;


int prime(long int pr) {
  int i;
  j = sqrt(pr);
  for (i = 2; i <= j; i++) {
    if (pr % i == 0)
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}


//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501681/suspend-and-resume-one-c-        thread-in-another
//Hilos calculo de Pi
void ThreadB_Activity()
{
  // Wait until ThreadA() sends data
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
  }

  std::cout << "Thread B is processing data\n";
  data += " after processing";
  // Send data back to ThreadA through the condition variable
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Thread B signals data processing completed\n";
  }

  /*aqui hay que poner la jugada para que avance*/
  if (contadorDos == 0) {
    cout << "\nGETTING P & Q PRIME NUMBERS";
  }

  cout <<"\nPorcentaje de realización del Hilo B : " <<porcentajeA<<"% \n";
  porcentajeA =porcentajeA + porcentajeTempDos;
  cout<<"fin del hilo B\n";
  cv.notify_one();
}

//hiloRSA
void ThreadA_Activity()
{
  std::cout<<"Thread A started "<<std::endl;
  data = "Example data";
  // send data to the worker thread
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    ready = true;
    std::cout << "Thread A signals data are ready to be processed\n";
  }

  cout << "\nHilo RSA al : " << porcentajetotal << "% \n";
  porcentajetotal = porcentajetotal + porcentajeB;
  cv.notify_one();//notify to ThreadB that he can start doing his job

  // wait for the Thread B
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
  }
  std::cout << "Back in Thread A , data = " << data << '\n';

  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1000 ));
  std::cout<<"end of Thread A"<<std::endl;
}

int main() { /* Explicacion de Hilos       http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/  */

  //Manejo de porcentajes de los hilos
  //25% 50% 75% 100%

  cout <<"Interaciones de 4 fases\n";
  cout <<"------------------------------------\n";
  numeroint = 4;
  porcentajetotal = 100 / numeroint;
  porcentajeA = porcentajetotal;
  porcentajeB = porcentajetotal;
  porcentajeA = porcentajeB;

  cout << "Valores de las interaciones\n";
  cout <<"------------------------------------\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < numeroint; i++) {

    std::thread ThreadB(ThreadB_Activity);
    std::thread ThreadA(ThreadA_Activity);

    ThreadB.join();
    ThreadA.join();
  }

  cout <<"------------------------------------\n";
  std::cout << "Back in main , data = " << data << '\n';
  cout <<"------------------------------------\n";

  cout << "\nHilos a ejecutarse\n";
  cout <<"------------------------------------\n";

  std::thread HiloB(calculoPi); //crea un nuevo hilo que se llama calculoPI
  std::thread HiloA(RSA); //crea un nuevo hilo que se llama RSA

  //http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/ */
  //Sincronizacion de hilos
  HiloB.join(); // lo pausa hasta que el primero termine
  HiloA.join(); //lo pausa hasta que el segundo termine

  std::cout << "Completado Pi y RSA\n";
  cout <<"------------------------------------\n";

  return 0;
}


void calculoPi() {
  // calcula el resultado de PI

  srand((unsigned int) time((time_t *) NULL));

  int in = 0, out = 0;
  double d, x, y, pi;
  long long cont = 10516267; // ou qualquer outro valor

  while (cont-- > 0) {

    x = (double) rand() / (double) INT_MAX;
    y = (double) rand() / (double) INT_MAX;

    d = x * x + y*y;

    (d <= 1.0) ? in++ : out++;

  }
  pi = 4.0 * (float) in / (float) (in + out);
  printf("\n");
  printf("pi (aproximado) = %2.30f\n", pi);

}

void RSA()
// Calculo del encriptado de rsa
//http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-rsa-algorithm/
{

  p = 47;
  flag = prime(p);
  q = 53;
  flag = prime(q);

  cout << "\nOpteniendo mensaje desde el .TXT\n";
  fflush(stdin);

  // Se lee el txt
  ifstream fin("Archivo.txt");
  fin >> msg;


  for (i = 0; msg[i] != NULL; i++) {
    m[i] = msg[i];
  }

  n = p * q;
  t = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
  ce();
  printPossibleValues();
  encrypt();
  decrypt();
}

void printPossibleValues() {
  cout << "\nLos posible valores de E y D son\n";
  for (i = 0; i < j - 1; i++)
    cout << e[i] << "\t" << d[i] << "\n";
}

void ce()
{
  int k;
  k = 0;
  for (i = 2; i < t; i++)
  {
    if (t % i == 0)
      continue;

    flag = prime(i);
    if (flag == 1 && i != p && i != q)
    {
      e[k] = i;
      flag = cd(e[k]);
      if (flag > 0)
      {
        d[k] = flag;
        k++;
      }

      if (k == 99)
        break;
    }
  }
}

long int cd(long int x)
{
  long int k = 1;
  while (1)
  {
    k = k + t;
    if (k % x == 0)
      return (k / x);
  }
}

void encrypt()
{
  long int pt, ct, key = e[0], k, len;
  i = 0;
  len = strlen(msg);

  while (i != len)
  {
    pt = m[i];
    pt = pt - 96;
    k = 1;

    for (j = 0; j < key; j++)
    {
      k = k * pt;
      k = k % n;
    }

    temp[i] = k;
    ct = k + 96;
    en[i] = ct;
    i++;
  }

  en[i] = -1;

  cout << "\nEl mensaje encriptado es\n";

  for (i = 0; en[i] != -1; i++)
    printf("%c", en[i]);
}

void decrypt()
{
  long int pt, ct, key = d[0], k;
  i = 0;

  while (en[i] != -1)
  {
    ct = temp[i];
    k = 1;

    for (j = 0; j < key; j++)
    {
      k = k * ct;
      k = k % n;
    }

    pt = k + 96;
    m[i] = pt;
    i++;
  }

  m[i] = -1;
  cout << "\nEl mensaje desencriptado es\n";

  for (i = 0; m[i] != -1; i++)
    printf("%c", m[i]);
}
```

Comment: para que sistema operativo?

Comment: windows, el IDE que estoy usando es netbeans

Answer (score 3):

Con todos mis respetos, tu código es un caos. Un ejemplo:

```
int numeroint = 4;
int porcentajetotal = 100 / numeroint; // ¿Por qué no poner directamente 25?
porcentajeA = porcentajetotal;
porcentajeB = porcentajetotal;
porcentajeA = porcentajeB; // ¿Por qué esta asignación?
```

Y otro más:

```
cout <<"\nPorcentaje de realización del Hilo B : " <<porcentajeA<<"% \n"; // ¿No debería ser B?
porcentajeA =porcentajeA + porcentajeTempDos; // ¿No debería ser B?
cout<<"fin del hilo B\n";
```

Si no has recibido más respuestas a estas alturas es porque tu código es complicado de leer y de seguir. Necesita una profunda refactorización para que sea mínimamente legible. Te doy algunos consejos:

**Variables globales**

El primer problema que tiene tu programa es el uso abusivo de las variables globales. Las variables deben tener la menor vida posible... y declarar por defecto las variables como globales puede darte muchos problemas... sobretodo si trabajas con hilos (básicamente porque la misma variable puede ser modificada por dos hilos diferentes si no te das cuenta). Las variables globales deberían dejar de existir en tu programa (como mucho dejaría `mu`, `cv` y `ready`. ¿Eres capaz de saber qué valor tiene, por ejemplo, `j` en cada momento? Pues eso. Piensa que hay formas más elegantes y seguras de compartir información entre hilos.

**Función prime()**

Por otro lado, `prime()` debería devolver un booleano, ya que solo puede devolver dos resultados posibles: 1 (es primo) y 0 (no es primo):

```
bool prime(long int pr) {
  long int j = static_cast<long int>(sqrt(pr));
  for (long int i = 2; i <= j; i++) {
    if (pr % i == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Esto permite simplificar el código y pasar de, por ejemplo, esto:

```
flag = prime(i);
if (flag == 1 && i != p && i != q)
```

A esto:

```
if (prime(i) && i != p && i != q)
```

**Hilos con parámetros**

La clase `thread` permite enviar valores a los hilos a través de parámetros... puedes usar esta característica para compartir variables:

```
void ThreadB_Activity(int porcentaje);

std::thread ThreadB(ThreadB_Activity,porcentajeA);
```

Incluso podrías pasar referencias para compartir valores:

```
void ThreadB_Activity(int& porcentaje);

std::thread ThreadB(ThreadB_Activity,std::ref(porcentajeA));
```

**Conversiones**

Para hacer conversiones es preferible usar las propias de C++. Son más seguras y fáciles de localizar en código:

Cambiar esto:

```
srand((unsigned int) time((time_t *) NULL));
```

Por esto:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned_int>(time(NULL)));    // C++99
srand(static_cast<unsigned_int>(time(nullptr))); // C++11 (Recomendado)
```

**Tipos de datos**

`long int` es equivalente a `long`, más corto y legible.

Si una división involucra a, por ejemplo, un `double` con un `int` el resultado será siempre `double`: `double x = static_cast<double>(rand) / INT_MAX;`

Si los cálculos en general son con números estrictamente positivos, sería mejor usar `unsigned long` o `unsigned long long` a `long int`.

Para los arrays es preferible usar `std::array<long,100> m` a `long m[100]`. `std::array` dispone de muchas características que un array crudo no y la penalización de rendimiento tiende a cero.

**Valores de retorno**

Si una función tuviese que devolver dos o más valores puedes usar `std::pair` o `std::tuple` (este último si compilas con C++11 o posterior). Siempre es mejor que usar variables globales. Puedes almacenar sus elementos individuales en variables independientes usando la función `std::tie`. Como siempre, esto es preferible a usar variables globales:

```
std::pair<int,char> func()
{
  return std::make_pair(10,'f');
}

int main()
{
  int numero;
  char c;

  std::tie(numero,c) = func();
  std::cout << numero << ' ' << c << '\n';
}
```

**Bloqueo de hilos**

Y bueno, en cuanto al tema de los hilos... las esperas de las que comentas ya las estás implementando:

Bloqueo hasta que otro hilo notifica:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
```

Notificación de un hilo:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mu);
ready = true;
cv.notify_one(); // notificamos que el valor de `ready` ha cambiado
```

Por cierto, el bloqueo podrías dejarlo así:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
cv.wait(lk);
```

Y entonces ya no sería necesario usar `ready`. El hilo se quedaría esperando a que alguien llame a `cv.notify_one()` o a `cv.notify_all()`. En tu caso no tiene sentido usar `ready` ya que siempre que llamas a `cv.notify_one()` estás modificando a `true` el valor de `ready`. Este bloqueo está pensado para aquellos casos en los que la notificación no tiene por qué ir emparejada con el cambio de la variable (por ejemplo si el valor de `ready` dependiese de un proceso externo).

Si no te funciona en algún punto del código es preferible centrar la pregunta únicamente en ese punto... si lo que esperas es que alguien depure todo el programa por ti quizás deberías plantearte ofrecer un pago por dichos servicios.

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente código tienes dos hilos trabajando alternado, en ese ejemplo protegiendo un recurso compartido. 
Mas ejemplos y esa puedes encontrar en 
[mi articulo sobre condition_variable](http://www.impostorprogrammer.com/articles/modern_cpp/condition_variable_es.html)

```
std::mutex alternateThreadsMutex;
std::condition_variable runThread1condition;
std::atomic<bool> runThread1 = false;
std::atomic<bool> runThread2 = false;
std::condition_variable runThread2condition;
std::vector<int> threadWork;

void thread1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(alternateThreadsMutex);
        runThread1condition.wait(lock, []() { return runThread1.load(); });
        auto workSize = threadWork.size();
        if (workSize < 1000)
            threadWork.push_back(1);

        runThread1 = false;
        runThread2 = true;
        lock.unlock();

        runThread2condition.notify_one();
        if (++workSize >= 1000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void thread2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(alternateThreadsMutex);
        runThread2condition.wait(lock, []() { return runThread2.load(); });
        auto workSize = threadWork.size();
        if (workSize < 1000)
            threadWork.push_back(1);

        runThread2 = false;
        runThread1 = true;
        lock.unlock();
        runThread1condition.notify_one();
        if (++workSize >= 1000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}


void alternateThreads()
{
    std::thread t1(thread1);
    std::thread t2(thread2);

    runThread2 = true;
    runThread2condition.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << threadWork.size() << el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que me dices, te puedo decir que uses  `Sleep();` pero en realidad lo estarías pausando por un tiempo en milisegundos, ahora si quieres hacerlo como si fuera un booleano por que tu dices que quieres hacerlo cuando suceda un evento por lo que veo, entonces se debería utilizar el creador de threads de la librería estándar de `<windows.h>`

Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE tha; // nuevo handle para el thread

DWORD WINAPI threada(LPVOID arg)
{
    cout << "Me ejecuto sin problemas!" << endl;
    SuspendThread(tha); // auto suspencion
    cout << "Continua la ejecucion de tha!" << endl;
    return 0;
}



int main()
{

    tha = CreateThread(NULL,0,threada,NULL,0,NULL);

    Sleep(10000); // thread principal main(); durmiendo por 10 segundos!

    ResumeThread(tha); // continua tha! - se levanta la suspensión


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: `Sleep();` es solo un ejemplo, puedes llamar la función `ResumeThread();` ante cualquier evento que tu quieras.

Comment: Está usando la librería thread de c++. Lo que quiere es dormir un proceso hasta que el otro alcance un punto de control

Comment: Lo de la librería thread lo digo porque deberías contemplar dar una respuesta usa do dicha librería

Comment: @eferion hombre échale un vistazo a la librería `<thread>` y tu mismo veras a lo que me refiero, como te decía puedes usar `Sleep();` en lugar de usar `sleep_for();` para no usar `<chrono>` pero como te decía en la respuesta tu quieres pausar el thread hasta que ocurra un evento, y con `Sleep();` o `sleep_for();` lo que haces es hacerlo dormir por milisegundos, y eso no corresponde a lo que tu dices.

Comment: Eso lo sé, pero el estándar será compatible con cualquier plataforma, mientras que una solución con `windows.h` no

Comment: @eferion Primero antes que nada, yo pegunté para que sistema operativo era, el que hizo la pregunta dejando bien en claro que es para windows y yo aporté mi respuesta para dicho sistema operativo, comprendo que no forma parte del estándar de C++14.

Comment: No estoy criticando tu solución sino dando ideas para que la respuesta sea más universal. Yo no publico porque no tengo un pc a mano y no voy a responder alegremente... Los hilos no son para tomárselos a risa